# greek capital letters not displayed properly in PNAS style

Tags: math-mode, pnas

when using PNAS LaTeX template ([here](http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/latex.xhtml)), Greek capital letters get rendered incorrectly. for example,

```
    \Phi(\vect{x}, t | \vect{x}_0)
```

gets rendered as
[image].

i am using the following in my TeX source

```
    \documentclass{pnastwo}
    \usepackage{PNAStwoF}
    \usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath}
    \usepackage{url, graphicx, subfig, bbold}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{footmisc}
```

any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You have my sympathy: I find `pnastwo` one of the worst classes ever written. No surprise it breaks almost everything.

Answer (score 1):

*As a starting point*:

In `pnastwof` you have:

```
%% Dvipsone Names:
\def\timesroman{tir}
\def\timesbold{tib}
\def\timesitalic{tii}
\def\timesbolditalic{tibi}

%% Karl Berry Names:
%\def\timesroman{ptmr8t}
%\def\timesbold{ptmb8t}
%\def\timesitalic{ptmri8t}
%\def\timesbolditalic{ptmbi8t}

%% BlueSky or other TeX Systems, write in appropriate font name:
\def\timesroman{du801btr7t}
\def\timesbold{du801btb7t}
\def\timesitalic{du801bti7t}
\def\timesbolditalic{du801btbi7t}

\global\let\rmdefault\timesroman
\DeclareFontFamily{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{}
\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}{
    <-> \timesroman
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}
```

So I guess you will have to put in some replacement for `du801btr7t` and so on in order to get a valid `\timesroman` command which will be important for the later defined `\rmdefault`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i actually had to edit my PNAStwoF.sty file to uncomment the Karl Berry names and comment out the other ones for it to be able to compile properly.

Comment: @darXider Glad to hear that. Do you even need this file? It seems to be optional and just switching some fonts. Maybe you stay with the default.

Comment: well, not really, but it kind of makes the article look like the published version in PNAS. but it really is horribly programmed/designed...i had to significantly edit it to make it work with my version of TeX Live on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @LaRiFaRi. your answer made me take another look at my `PNAStwoF.sty` file. it now looks like this

```
    %% Times-Roman

    %% Dvipsone Names:
    %\def\timesroman{tir}
    %\def\timesbold{tib}
    %\def\timesitalic{tii}
    %\def\timesbolditalic{tibi}

    %% Karl Berry Names:
    %\def\timesroman{ptmr8t}
    %\def\timesbold{ptmb8t}
    %\def\timesitalic{ptmri8t}
    %\def\timesbolditalic{ptmbi8t}

    %% BlueSky or other TeX Systems, write in appropriate font name:
    %\def\timesroman{du801btr7t}
    %\def\timesbold{du801btb7t}
    %\def\timesitalic{du801bti7t}
    %\def\timesbolditalic{du801btbi7t}
```

(yes, it's all commented out!), and i now have my `\Phi` and `\Delta` back.